# Java : How to do image manipulation (pan, zoom, flip and rotate)?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d, affinetransform

I am making an Image viewer application for my own interest. I am using `JPanel` to display a `bufferedImage`.

**Objective - I want to manipulate the image and give user the options to zoom, pan, flip or rotate images.**

I am now able to zoom, pan and rotate. But the problem is that it is not the same as what you see when you open a .pdf file in **Microsoft Edge**.

I have added the code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ZoomAndPan1 extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage img;
    private boolean init = true;
    private int zoomLevel = 0;
    private int minZoomLevel = -20;
    private int maxZoomLevel = 10;
    private double zoomMultiplicationFactor = 1.2;

    private Point dragStartScreen;
    private Point dragEndScreen;
    private AffineTransform coordTransform = new AffineTransform();

    public ZoomAndPan1() throws IOException {
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                dragStartScreen = e.getPoint();
                dragEndScreen = null;
            }
        });
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                pan(e);
            }
        });
        this.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                if (e.isControlDown()) {
                    zoom(e);
                }
            }
        });
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("file.path"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int x = (int) (this.size().getWidth() - (img.getWidth() * .2)) / 2;
        int y = (int) (this.size().getHeight() - (img.getHeight() * .2)) / 2;

        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(x, y);
        at.scale(.2, .2);
        if (init) {
            g2.setTransform(at);
            init = false;
            coordTransform = g2.getTransform();
        } else {
            g2.setTransform(coordTransform);
        }

        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    private void pan(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
            dragEndScreen = e.getPoint();
            Point2D.Float dragStart = transformPoint(dragStartScreen);
            Point2D.Float dragEnd = transformPoint(dragEndScreen);
            double dx = dragEnd.getX() - dragStart.getX();
            double dy = dragEnd.getY() - dragStart.getY();
            coordTransform.translate(dx, dy);
            dragStartScreen = dragEndScreen;
            dragEndScreen = null;
            repaint();
        } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void zoom(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        try {
            int wheelRotation = e.getWheelRotation();
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            if (wheelRotation > 0) {
                if (zoomLevel < maxZoomLevel) {
                    zoomLevel++;
                    Point2D p1 = transformPoint(p);
                    coordTransform.scale(1 / zoomMultiplicationFactor, 1 / zoomMultiplicationFactor);
                    Point2D p2 = transformPoint(p);
                    coordTransform.translate(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), p2.getY() - p1.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            } else {
                if (zoomLevel > minZoomLevel) {
                    zoomLevel--;
                    Point2D p1 = transformPoint(p);
                    coordTransform.scale(zoomMultiplicationFactor, zoomMultiplicationFactor);
                    Point2D p2 = transformPoint(p);
                    coordTransform.translate(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), p2.getY() - p1.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Point2D.Float transformPoint(Point p1) throws NoninvertibleTransformException {
        AffineTransform inverse = coordTransform.createInverse();
        Point2D.Float p2 = new Point2D.Float();
        inverse.transform(p1, p2);
        return p2;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        return new Dimension(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Zoom and Pan ");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new ZoomAndPan1(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ZoomAndPan1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This code can do following things :

1. **Zoom in/out on CTRL + mouse scroll**
2. **Pan image on mouse drag**.

Limitations :

1. **Return to center when zoomed out.**
2. **Pan is not restricted with in the `Jpanel` or `viewport`  boundaries.**

I want to achieve this :

[image]

Unfortunately, the code does like this :

[image]

How to solve this ?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Can you explain more about what is happening now and what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: Have you seen the gif I attached?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHAhr.gif

Comment: I want to pan the image but only inside the `jpanel` or window boundaries...
Please try to run my code

Comment: OK that's what you want to achieve what is it doing now?

Comment: This is really i want to achieve:

1.  Zoom the image with in the mouse point. (done)
2. Pan image using mouse drag (done)..
but when I pan the image up to the outside it will disappear on the screen.

Comment: This what my code does.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoiBa.gif

Comment: In order for me to run your code, I need an image file in order to create a `BufferedImage`. Can I use any image file?

Comment: Yes sure.. you can use any image file (i prefer JPEG file)...

Comment: [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) has an example that I think solves your image panning requirement. As in that example, I think putting your image on a `JLabel` and making that `JLabel` the scrollable client for a `JScrollPane` is the way to go, rather than putting your image on a `JPanel`.

Comment: How can I implement it to my code

Comment: How does your question relate to [tag:pdfbox]? You tagged it so...

Comment: I am using the PDFBox library to convert pdf to images.

Comment: I have removed it. PDFBox has almost nothing to do with it (except maybe zoom but that is just a simple parameter), it is just the producer of the images.

Comment: *"you can use any image file"* One way to get image(s) for an example is to **hot link** to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: Can someone help me .. 
I tried the @Abra suggestion but I didnt work with my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple program that demonstrates what I suggested, namely a large image set as the icon of a `JLabel` and the `JLabel` is the scrollable client for a `JScrollPane`. Note that I set the preferred size of the `JScrollPane` to 800 x 600 pixels because the default behavior is to make the `JScrollPane` the same size as its scrollable client. The image dimensions are 2312 x 1536 pixels which means it is larger than my computer screen. So if I don't set the preferred size, when you run the program the `JFrame` overflows the screen. You don't see all of the `JFrame`. This is on purpose so you can see how the image scrolls. The URL for the image is https://unsplash.com/photos/l68Z6eF2peA. And here is the code, which is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

By the way, I downloaded and saved the image in a file that I named *worldmap.jpg*

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ScrolImg implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;
/* Start 'Runnable' interface methods. */
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }
/* End 'Runnable' interface methods. */
    private JScrollPane createMainPanel() {
        Icon ico = new ImageIcon("worldmap.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(ico);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(label);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("ScrolImg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScrolImg instance = new ScrolImg();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this code will help you complete your project.

Comment: Thank you for your help.After a series of trial and error I was able to control my pan function. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to control the pan funtion..

I replaced my pan function with this listener. It applies the same concept as putting the Image in a label. And I cant afford to use labels since I would be writing on top of the image itself so this is what I did.

```
//map - represents the container or component the image was drawn.
//then I added a ScrollPane on map..


map.setAutoscrolls(true);
add(new JScrollPane(map));

MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
  private Point origin;

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      origin = new Point(e.getPoint());
      System.out.println("click");
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
      if (origin != null) {
        JViewport viewPort = (JViewport) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JViewport.class, map);
        if (viewPort != null) {
              int deltaX = origin.x - e.getX();
              int deltaY = origin.y - e.getY();

              Rectangle view = viewPort.getViewRect();
              view.x += deltaX;
              view.y += deltaY;

              map.scrollRectToVisible(view);

         }
      }                
   }
};
```